# how to merge keys in dictionary outside of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to get dictionary with same keys and merge its values and if there is a duplicate leave only one value of duplicate.

```
data = {"test1":["data1", "data2"],
   "test1":["data3", "data4", "data2"],
   "test2":["1data", "2data"],
   "test2":["3data", "4data", "2data"]
   }

desired_result = {"test1":["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"],
                 "test2":["1data", "2data", "3data", "4data"]
                 }
```

any ideas how to get result?

Comment: You can't have dictionary with same keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need create `list` of `dict` **(because you can't have dictionary with same keys)** then iterate over them and `extend` them to `list` with `key` of `dict` then use `set` for delete `duplicated` like below:

```
data = [{"test1":["data1", "data2"]},{"test1":["data3", "data4", "data2"]},{"test2":["1data", "2data"]},{"test2":["3data", "4data", "2data"]}]

from collections import defaultdict

rslt_out = defaultdict(list)
for dct in data:
    for k,v in dct.items():
        rslt_out[k].extend(v)
     

for k,v in rslt_out.items():
    rslt_out[k] = list(set((v)))
        
print(rslt_out)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'test1': ['data3', 'data4', 'data2', 'data1'],
             'test2': ['2data', '3data', '1data', '4data']})
```